# Form Alignment CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

This is one thing that I really hate within development is forms.  Below is my code and what I am trying to do is align the inputs with the labels `Name: input`.  Is there a rule that you use to help remember when coding forms?

CSS:

```
 #newwebsiteForm form{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0;
    width:480px;
    position: relative;
}
#newwebsiteForm label{
    width:240px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
#newwebsiteForm input{
    width:240px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="content">
                <h1>Free Quote</h1>
                    <p>Please fill out the below questionnaire to receive your free web development quote</p>
                        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                            <select name="requiredOption" id="requiredOption">
                                <option id="pleaseselect" value="pleaseselect">Please Select Your Required Quote</option>
                                <option id="newwebsite" value="newwebsite">New Website</option>
                                <option id="websiteredevelopment" value="websiteredevelopment">Website Redevelopment</option>
                                <option id="other" value="other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                        <div id="newwebsiteSection">
                            <form action="" id="newwebsiteForm" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                            <fieldset>  
                            <label>Do You Require Hosting?</label><input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</input><input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No</input>

                            <label>Do You Require A Domain?</label><input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</input><input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No</input>

                            <label>Do You Have A Logo?</label><input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</input><input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No</input>

                            <label>What is your Domain?</label>
                            <input type="url" name="domain" value="http://example.com"></input></div>

                            <label>Type of site Required?<label>

                                <select name="newwebsiteType" id="newwebsiteType">
                                <option value="shoppingCart">Shopping Cart</option>
                                <option value="CMS">Content Management System</option>
                                <option value="static">Static Website</option>
                                <option value="otherDevelopment">Other Development</option>
                            </select>

                            <label>Do You Require A Design?</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</input><input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No</input>

                            <label>Three Favorite colors?</label>
                                <input name="color1" value=""></input>
                                <input name="color2" value=""></input>
                                <input name="color3" value=""></input>

                                <label>What are your favorite websites?</label>
                                <input type="text" name="fav1" value=""></input>
                                <input type="text" name="fav2" value=""></input>
                                <input type="text" name="fav3" value=""></input>

                            <label>Comments?</label>
                            <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Quote Request">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                            <div id="websiteredevelopmentSection">
                                <p>Website Redevelopment</p>
                            </div>
                                <div id="otherSection">
                                    <p>Other</p>
                                </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: It's a little taboo to admit, but many of us still use tables for forms. CSS is still a pain for some form layouts, and tables work.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would agree and I am determined to master this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to the question: [`<div>` usage correctly? Can't get the columns to line up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182966/div-usage-correctly-cant-get-the-columns-to-line-up/7186736#7186736): You can also check my comments there for some reference when dealing with semantically-correct forms.

The approach you will need to be in habit of is *always* structure your markup *correctly* first before jumping to any CSS *(or styling)*.

A `<form>` is composed of the following:

1. The `<form>` itself.
2. The `<fieldset>`: acts a the container of the different sections of your `<form>`
3. The `<legend>`: acts as the heading of the `<fieldset>`
4. The `<input />`: for fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, and submit button
5. The `<button>`: an alternative for `<input type="submit">`, which can wrap something 
   inside of it.
6. The `<select>`: a list of values inside a drop-down menu.
7. The `<label>`: from the name itself, the **label** of the `<input />`, `<button>` and `<select>`

To illustrate, you can check this example:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form Heading: </legend>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Group 1 Heading: </legend>
            <label for="input-id">Input Label: </label>
            <input id="input-id" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Group 2 Heading: </legend>
            <label for="select-id">Select Label: </label>
            <select id="select-id">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

With the exception of radio *(`<input type="radio" />`)* and checkboxes *(`<input type="checkbox" />`)*, where the `<label>` should come **after** the `<input />`

Answer (score 1):

Just because tables are the easier option doesn't make using them right.

Here's a great article about css form design.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

The author suggests storing each label/input element in an ordered list element keeping them grouped.

I've just used this to implement a bunch of forms for various mini sites and it worked a treat!
You can align the label next to the input or above just by changing the ol li label element's display property from display:inline-block to display:block respectively.

Getting the text to align next to a radio button or checkbox can be a bit tricky but is possible by adding and styling a span element.

BEST OF ALL IT'S CROSS BROWSER COMPATIBLE!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the label element as follows to correctly align them:

```
<FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>
<LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>
<LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</P>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrap each input/label pair in a `<div>`. This helps a lot with styling.

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
</div>
```